# PlotLegends from a List

Tags: plotting

I want to generate plots showing dependence of a function on another parameter, and automatically add correct PlotLegend that says which graph is which parameter.

```
f[x_, a_] := x + a ; Params = {1, 2};
Plot[Evaluate[f[x,#] & /@ Params], {x, 0, 1},  
    PlotLegends -> {StringForm["a = ``", #] & /@ Params }]
```

But this doesnt work, Mathematica complains that functions and legend are not the same shape.

Answer (score 2):

If we look at the `FullForm` of `StringForm`'s result we get:

```
StringForm["a = ``", #] & /@ {1, 2} // FullForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see that the result of `StringForm` is not a string (which is what `PlotLegends` needs), but an output form like `TableForm` which is used to prettify things for *printed output*.

Instead, you could use:

```
f[x_, a_] := x + a; Params = {1, 2};
Plot[Evaluate[f[x, #] & /@ Params], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> ("a = " <> ToString[#] & /@ Params)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]